# How to structure SVN Repositories?

Tags: svn, testing, module, tags, branch

I have a problem with my SVN structure.
How can I implement the "best practices" in the next case?

I have the following subdirectories:

```
SYSTEM/
      /trunk
      /branches
      /tags
      /testing
```

Conditions:

- Development Team do 'commit' at branches.
- The system have a lot of modules that evolve independently.
- System Binaries are generated from the different versions of the modules (not always the latest versions of the modules).
- Testing directories must stored the different system completed versions.

I think the main problem is to save the different versions of the modules and to tag a complete version of the complete system.

Anyone have a similar structura or can help me with this issue?